# Is there any solution for generating Business Logic Classes and Database logic classes from MYSQL database table?

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, code-generation

I am looking for a  solution for creating BO and DAL classes as well as the Stored procedure from MYSQL database using phpmyadim. I have solution for the mssql server database but i needed a good solution for the MYSQL database. There are many solution but there are not good enough for this kind of work.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. What have you tried and why wasn't it good enough for you?

Comment: @IsaacBennetch i used dal generator for c# and sql server. I just have to pass the connection string for specific database then when i select any database it create basic Database and C# functionalists like insert, update, delete getAll stored procedures, C# functions and BO objects. But i have tried different solutions like link(http://planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=7752&lngWId=10) but it only create BO Classes. I need that solution which is like [link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/codegenconnect/) this. thanks